# Exoplayer in android tv don't reproduce (.m3u8) file in live streaming

Tags: android-studio, android-tv, exoplayer

hi guys i'm having a problem trying to reproduce live streaming video using  the file .m3u8 ,when i try to reproduce the video don't show any image and show this error in the Log.

[image]

To reproduce the .m3u8 file, i use the  HLS class that is provided by the Exoplayer on android tv .

i'm not sure why is this error come up ,because  if i compile it with the android 6.0 actually i have the image and the sound  , but if try it in lower versions this error come up again

Comment: What does your player class look like? Are you correctly going through the ExoPlayer initialization flow?

Comment: i'm trying an example from the samples of google anyways i'll be on touch....

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Gave up using straight ExoPlayer and used ExoMedia wrapped in VideoView class. Works great:

https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia